# how to get the value of a span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the contents of a span tag but what I have isn't working. An alert shows an empty dialog box. I've tried the following but nothing works.

```
var test=$('#test').val()
var test=$('span#test').val()
var test=$('td span#test').val()
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`span` elements do not have a `value` property.

Instead, use `html()` for the HTML or `text()` for the text nodes.

Comment: Hey Alex. When you say text nodes. what do you mean?

Comment: @jim The text nodes for that element and all children's.

Comment: I'm really new to JQ so could you please explain or point me to something that explains it in noob terms? :)

Comment: @jim Basically if you took the `innerHTML` of the element and removed all tags :)

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm a super noob because I don't even know what innerHTML is. I'm going to have to do some reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span#test').text()
```

will give you the text. val() is for the attribute value

Answer (score 1):

You are correct almost, but instead of the val() to Need to say html().

```
 var test=$('#test').html();
 var test=$('span#test').html();
 var test=$('td span#test').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

a span doesn't have a value attribute.

You should instead do the following

```
var test=$('span#test').html()
```

or

```
var test=$('span#test').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var test=$('#test').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.text()`. `.val()` is only for input elements.

```
var test = $('span#test').text();
```